# node.js / ES6 / class creation : SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I try to create a class on my node.js / express app.

It works in basic js / prototype mode such as :

```
function MyClass() { 
    /* constructor code */
};

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    /* method code */
};

module.exports = MyClass;
```

But I want to do use the class, constructor, extends, ... keywords.

I've try that :

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        /* constructor code */
    }

    myMethod() {
        /* method code */
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work, the error is :

```
class MyClass {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

My command line to launch the app with all harmony options :

```
node `node --v8-options | grep harmony | cut -d ' ' -f | xargs` my-app.js
```

An idea to launch my app correctly please ?

Comment: Google's V8 engine that Node is built on [hasn't yet released support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#class) for ES6 `class`es. In general, ES6 feature support shouldn't be assumed as the [standard is still in "draft."](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) (Side note: `node --harmony` will enable all available Harmony options.)

Comment: Did you solve this, as I have the same error?

Comment: Yes, all is in the previous comment. You can't use all ES6 features for the moment

Comment: How did you get the cut command to work without providing an argument to -f ?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with [io.js](https://iojs.org/es6.html)

```
iojs --use_strict --harmony_classes my-app.js
```

Or on node.js with [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)

```
var traceur = require('traceur');
traceur.require.makeDefault(function(file) {
  return file.indexOf('node_modules') == -1;
});

require('./my-app').run();
```

Make sure to test the new features before using them, some are not supported.
Edit: You can check the compatibility list from [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: Worth noting the order of these switches are important - the file name must be specified after the switches otherwise you will just receive the same error.

Comment: This does not really answer the original question.

Answer (score 7):

You need a newer version of nodejs.  The `class` keyword is [supported in 4.4.x](http://node.green/#class), but I'm personally seeing it work in v4.2.6. (Not entirely sure what version of v8 released it, which is what would tell the node version.)

Comment: I had two versions of node installed. Ran "where node" and realized I was using the wrong one

Comment: @Hoppe - You might want to look at nodist.  It allows you to set one version of node as the global default, and a different one for use in the local directory.  My team has found it to be very helpful for avoiding versioning hassles.

https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem.

It was caused because I downloaded nodejs' source code than built/ compiled it on my Ubuntu. `./configure` then `make` and `make install`.

For some reason the ES6 reserved words like `class` and `extends` were throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word, even when using `--harmony` flag.

It was solved by me downloading the nodejs binaries for linux (https://nodejs.org/download/).

Now class and extends work even without `--harmony` flag.

I believe the issue came about from my building/ compiling process. For some reason the ES6 additions were not built or configured properly.

The binaries, to my understanding, are built completely and correctly for linux already and therefore the ES6 is added and configured correctly.

Comment: what version of node are you using?  the 12.6 binary version on windows doesn't seem to work