# How to run NodeJS with ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8

I want to use:

```
class FOO extends
    // do stuff
    constructor() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
module.exports = FOO;
```

Output of `nodejs --version` = `v0.12.7`

Also running `nodejs --harmony script.js` is not accepting the classes.

I keep getting a:

```
class TODORouter extends
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Comment: Your question may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177485/node-js-es6-class-creation-syntaxerror-unexpected-reserved-word

Answer (score 2):

You may either use IO.js or run noe with the harmony flag, eg

`node --harmony app.js`

This might help: [What does `node --harmony` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351965/what-does-node-harmony-do)