# Node.js application SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 'class'

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to Node.js and just started building an application using Eclipse and Nodeclipse plug-ins. When I run the app using Node core.js it works fine, but using Eclipse it shows me the following error:

```
/home/sarojs/projects/Core/security.js:3
  class Security {
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sarojs/projects/node/liveprojects/ecurvInc/Core/core.js:12:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I can't figure out what is wrong here. I googled for the solution and found some resources [Unexpected reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177485/node-js-es6-class-creation-syntaxerror-unexpected-reserved-word), but I didn't understand how to incorporate it into Eclipse.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
 "bluebird": "^3.4.0",
 "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
 "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
 "cors": "^2.8.1",
 "debug": "~2.0.0",
 "express": "~4.9.0",
 "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
 "express-session": "^1.13.0",
 "mysql": "^2.11.1",
 "passport": "^0.3.2",
 "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
 }
}
```

- Node.js version: 4.4.6
- IDE: Eclipse Mars 1 with Nodeclipse plug-ins

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not writing in an environment that understands ES6 it's going to warn you about stuff that isn't ES5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `class` declaration is an ES6 Feature. ES6 features [are hardly supported](http://node.green/) in node 4.4.6. Try [updating](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) it and running `npm install` again

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class

Comment: i tried to update the node version to 6.1.0 and ran the project in eclipse but still the same issue persists.

Comment: Thanks ! i updated node and it worked!! thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem after scratching my head for so many hours.

As @Tom M said the class declaration is an ES6 feature and previously i had node 4.2.6 but when i updated it to v4.6.2 the error vanished.

I downloaded the binary from [here](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.4.6/) and install the node by extracting the file manually to my /usr/local directory and then ran

```
 npm install
```

You can find how to install node binary manually [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/10/install-nodejs-npm-linux/)

Comment: on *nix systems you can just install and maintain nodejs via package-manager (homebrew, yum, pacman, apt etc.). See: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript classes were recently introduced in ECMAScript 6. They are syntactic sugar over the previous prototypical inheritance model.

You can check which version of node supports class syntax over [node.green](http://node.green/)

You can see the class concept is supported from v4.6.2 so try to update it to at least 4.6.2.But not all the ES6 feature are supported by this version.